# How to upload image file to Amazon S3 using aws-sdk and Nativescript

Tags: image, amazon-s3, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to upload an image local PNG to Amazon S3 using aws-sdk, but the file that is arriving in Bucket is double the bytes and corrupted.

I'm able to list files, create Buckets among others.

Nativescript: 5.2.4

npm: 6.4.1

node: 10.15.3

I'm tried read using method file.readText()

```
 await file.readText().then(
    (content) => {
        this.binarySource = content;
    });
```

Init Amazon S3

```
        AWS.config.update({
            region: "us-east-1",
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: this.chaveAmazonS3,
                secretAccessKey: this.tokenAmazonS3
            }
        });
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            apiVersion: "2006-03-01"
        });
        this.amazonS3 = s3;
```

Get file and upload using putObject

```
        let artefato = '/data/user/0/org.nativescript.aixlab/files/midias/41_000014_1558633914086.png';
        let diretorioS3 = 'dirbucket/';

        let filename = artefato.substring(artefato.lastIndexOf(separator) + 1);
        filename = diretorioS3 + filename;

        const file: File = File.fromPath(artefato);
        this.binarySource = await file.readTextSync();
        // await file.readText().then(
        //     (content) => {
        //         this.binarySource = content;
        //     });

        console.log("filename", filename, file.size, this.binarySource.length, artefato);

        let params = {
            Bucket: this.bucketAmazonS3,
            Key: filename,
            Body: this.binarySource,
            ContentLength: this.binarySource.length,
            ContentType: 'image/png',
        };

        try {
            //let options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
            let response = await this.amazonS3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
                console.log("PUT", err, data);
            }); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Erro putObjectBucket", error);
            return false;
        }
```

Result in console

```
JS: 
JS: PUT null {
JS:   "ETag": "\"913b7bda195f7bebfdaff5e5b10138a0\""
JS: }
```

This is values of File (Module) and return file.readTextSync

file.size = 193139

this.binarySource.length = 182599

Object in Amazon Bucket

342.6 KB

I expect the PNG file in Amazon S3 Bucket in binary format.

I can not save in base64 format because of other legacy applications.

Comment: Are you referring to the aws-sdk for node.js?

Comment: Yes,
I'm using aws-sdk for nodejs, but in Nativescript 

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-nodeify)

Comment: First of all, you are reading the image as text which is not correct. For binary data, you should read it as `readSync()` but it is going to return the bytes in native format. Also NativeScript's Http module (which should be used by AWS SDK under the hood), doesn't support uploading binary data. So I doubt this could help you. You might have to upload as Base64 string Or may use background http plugin with necessary parameters that AWS can understand.

Comment: Thanks, @Manoj ! 
I'll use background-http to upload.